# How to use a batch size bigger than zero in Bert Sequence Classification

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

[Hugging Face documentation describes](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/bert.html#bertforsequenceclassification) how to do a sequence classification using a Bert model:

```
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertForSequenceClassification
import torch

tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

input_ids = torch.tensor(tokenizer.encode("Hello, my dog is cute", add_special_tokens=True)).unsqueeze(0)  # Batch size 1
labels = torch.tensor([1]).unsqueeze(0)  # Batch size 1
outputs = model(input_ids, labels=labels)

loss, logits = outputs[:2]
```

However, there is only example for batch size 1. How to implement it when we have a list of phrases and want to use a bigger batch size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in that example `unsqueeze` is used to add a dimension to the input/labels, so that it is an array of size `(batch_size, sequence_length)`. If you want to use a batch size > 1, you can build an array of sequences instead, like in the following example:

```py
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertForSequenceClassification
import torch

tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

sequences = ["Hello, my dog is cute", "My dog is cute as well"]
input_ids = torch.tensor([tokenizer.encode(sequence, add_special_tokens=True) for sequence in sequences])
labels = torch.tensor([[1], [0]]) # Labels depend on the task
outputs = model(input_ids, labels=labels)

loss, logits = outputs[:2]
```

In that example, both sequences get encoded in the same number of tokens so it's easy to build a tensor containing both sequences, but if they have a differing amount of elements you would need to pad the sequences and tell the model which tokens it should attend to (so that it ignores the padded values) using an attention mask.

There is an entry in the [glossary](https://huggingface.co/transformers/glossary.html#attention-mask) concerning attention masks which explains their purpose and usage. You pass this attention mask to the model when calling its forward method.

Comment: It worked, thanks! As you said, this case was a coincidence were both phrases had the same number of tokens, so I implemented a function to add a 0 padding in phrases with different length, but I still have to implement the attention mask using. As for the labels, how do I know when to use [1], [0] or other single-element array?

Comment: This depends on your task. You would need to determine different classes for your sequence classification, each class having a numerical index (e.g. 0 for your first class, 1 for your second class and 2 for your third class). You would then have to finetune this model on your specific task.

Comment: So, if my problem has 20 classes, and I'm trying to predict 3 phrases, I should build an [[0, 1, ..., 19], [0, 1, ..., 19], [0, 1, ..., 19]] array?